# How to add content between sub-item bullets in Rmarkdown

Tags: html, r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am trying to add text in-between sub-item bullets; however, the bullet following the content is displayed as a code block when the page is rendered. Following is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
---
title: "My HTML page"
---

- Bullet 1

    + Sub-item 1

My content here

    + Sub-item 2

My content here
```

The problem here is that `sub-item 2` is displayed as a block of code in the rendered html page. Is there any solution to this?

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two spaces ( = new line) after *Sub-item 1*
then start your content on the next line :

```
---
title: "My HTML page"
---

- Bullet 1

    + Sub-item 1  
My content here

    + Sub-item 2  
My content here
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, if I add any content after a sub-item, that content has to be on the next line? There is no way to add a line between the sub-item and the content?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I face this problem, I add a full carriage return and then type \n, with another full carriage return, being mindful of preserving the appropriate tabbing.

I realise that the following code will leave you with a duplicated *Bullet 1*, but I can't seem to find another way for you. Being more specific, for your example, this would be:

```
---
title: "My HTML page"
output: html_document
---

  - Bullet 1

    - Sub-item 1 

\n

My content here

\n

  - Bullet 1

    - Sub-item 2

\n

My content here
```

I hope that works well enough for you.

Comment: I just tested your script and the issue is that the sub-items are vertically aligned with `Bullet 1`, which means that they are not sub-items technically. I tried to transform them into sub-items but adding an extra tab and the same problem persists.